# Transpose DataFrame Without Aggregation in Spark with scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, transpose

I looked number different solutions online, but count not find what I am trying to achine. 
Please help me on this.

I am using Apache Spark 2.1.0 with Scala. Below is my dataframe:

```
+-----------+-------+
|COLUMN_NAME| VALUE |
+-----------+-------+
|col1       | val1  |
|col2       | val2  |
|col3       | val3  |
|col4       | val4  |
|col5       | val5  |
+-----------+-------+
```

I want this to be transpose to, as below:

```
+-----+-------+-----+------+-----+
|col1 | col2  |col3 | col4 |col5 |
+-----+-------+-----+------+-----+
|val1 | val2  |val3 | val4 |val5 |
+-----+-------+-----+------+-----+
```

Comment: What if two records have the same `COLUMN_NAME` but different `VALUE`? What should be the value then? And if you know there are no such repetitions, your dataframe is either very small (in which case you can just collect it and transform using plain Scala) or the result would have too many columns.

Comment: Two records never will have the same column names. In fact I am getting the table insert/update details coming in the multiple rows, one column with columnn-names and other with values, and my plan is to tranpose them into dataframe and update them directly into the Kudu database.
                                                                                                                                      
First column values coming as schema and send column values coming as values. So I need to build dataframe out of it. Please let me know if you have any other suggestions/thoughts.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If your *dataframe is small enough as in the question*, then you can *collect COLUMN_NAME to form schema* and *collect VALUE to form the rows* and then *create a new dataframe* as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
//creating schema from existing dataframe
val schema = StructType(df.select(collect_list("COLUMN_NAME")).first().getAs[Seq[String]](0).map(x => StructField(x, StringType)))
//creating RDD[Row] 
val values = sc.parallelize(Seq(Row.fromSeq(df.select(collect_list("VALUE")).first().getAs[Seq[String]](0))))
//new dataframe creation
sqlContext.createDataFrame(values, schema).show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+----+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|
+----+----+----+----+----+
|val1|val2|val3|val4|val5|
+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: You're awesome Ramesh ! This is exactly what I need. Thank you so much for your help. Performance wise this is better than Pivot.

Comment: Great to hear that @MarutiK, don't forget to upvote when you would be eligible ;)

Comment: How can we do this in pyspark ?

Answer (score 19):

You can do this using `pivot`, but you still need aggregation but what if you have multiple `value` for a `COLUMN_NAME`?

```
val df = Seq(
  ("col1", "val1"),
  ("col2", "val2"),
  ("col3", "val3"),
  ("col4", "val4"),
  ("col5", "val5")
).toDF("COLUMN_NAME", "VALUE")

df
  .groupBy()
  .pivot("COLUMN_NAME").agg(first("VALUE"))
  .show()

+----+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|
+----+----+----+----+----+
|val1|val2|val3|val4|val5|
+----+----+----+----+----+
```

EDIT:

if your dataframe is really that small as in your example, you can collect it as `Map`:

```
val map = df.as[(String,String)].collect().toMap
```

and then apply [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49386299/spark-convert-map-to-a-single-row-dataframe/49386539#49386539)

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response ! Greatly appreciated ! It worked :) . The only thing is because of pivot, it is slow.

Comment: Hey Raphael, I know we can do this using Map as well, but I couldn't achieve the results. Please share if you have logic with Map.

Comment: @MarutiK just call `toSeq` on your map, first, then apply my answer

Comment: I could able to do toSeq and after that it is failing with groupBy() for empty values. I am getting error as "      <console>:46: error: not enough arguments for method groupBy: (f: ((String, String)) => K)scala.collection.immutable.Map[K,Seq[(String, String)]]   ". Any advise on this.

Comment: @RaphaelRoth Thanks for your answer. What if there is only one column? I tried this solution for it and I get an extra row, how can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 2):

Another solution though lengthy using crosstab.

```
 val dfp = spark.sql(""" with t1 (
 select  'col1' c1, 'val1' c2  union all
 select  'col2' c1, 'val2' c2  union all
 select  'col3' c1, 'val3' c2  union all
 select  'col4' c1, 'val4' c2  union all
 select  'col5' c1, 'val5' c2
  )  select   c1  COLUMN_NAME,   c2  VALUE     from t1
""")
dfp.show(50,false)

+-----------+-----+
|COLUMN_NAME|VALUE|
+-----------+-----+
|col1       |val1 |
|col2       |val2 |
|col3       |val3 |
|col4       |val4 |
|col5       |val5 |
+-----------+-----+

val dfp2=dfp.groupBy("column_name").agg( first($"value") as "value" ).stat.crosstab("value", "column_name")
dfp2.show(false)

+-----------------+----+----+----+----+----+
|value_column_name|col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|
+-----------------+----+----+----+----+----+
|val1             |1   |0   |0   |0   |0   |
|val3             |0   |0   |1   |0   |0   |
|val2             |0   |1   |0   |0   |0   |
|val5             |0   |0   |0   |0   |1   |
|val4             |0   |0   |0   |1   |0   |
+-----------------+----+----+----+----+----+

val needed_cols = dfp2.columns.drop(1)

needed_cols: Array[String] = Array(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)

val dfp3 = needed_cols.foldLeft(dfp2) { (acc,x) => acc.withColumn(x,expr(s"case when ${x}=1 then value_column_name else 0 end")) }
dfp3.show(false)

+-----------------+----+----+----+----+----+
|value_column_name|col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|
+-----------------+----+----+----+----+----+
|val1             |val1|0   |0   |0   |0   |
|val3             |0   |0   |val3|0   |0   |
|val2             |0   |val2|0   |0   |0   |
|val5             |0   |0   |0   |0   |val5|
|val4             |0   |0   |0   |val4|0   |
+-----------------+----+----+----+----+----+

dfp3.select( needed_cols.map( c => max(col(c)).as(c)) :_* ).show

+----+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|
+----+----+----+----+----+
|val1|val2|val3|val4|val5|
+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

To enhance Ramesh Maharjan's answer, collect and then convert it to a map.

```
val mp = df.as[(String,String)].collect.toMap
```

with a dummy dataframe, we can build further using foldLeft

```
val f = Seq("1").toDF("dummy")

mp.keys.toList.sorted.foldLeft(f) { (acc,x) => acc.withColumn(mp(x),lit(x) ) }.drop("dummy").show(false)

+----+----+----+----+----+
|val1|val2|val3|val4|val5|
+----+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|
+----+----+----+----+----+
```