# create array of columns in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with single row and multiple columns. I would like it to convert it into multiple rows.
I had found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61469585/transpose-dataframe-single-row-to-column-in-spark-with-scala) on the stackoverflow.

The question answers how it can be done in scala but I wanted to do this in pyspark. I tried to replicate the code in pyspark but I wasn't able to do that.

I am not able to convert the below code in scala to python:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
var ColumnsAndValues: Array[Column] = df.columns.flatMap { c => {Array(lit(c), col(c))}}
val df2 = df1.withColumn("myMap", map(ColumnsAndValues: _*))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Pyspark you can use `create_map` function to create map column. And a list comprehension with `itertools.chain` to get the equivalent of scala flatMap :

```
import itertools
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

columns_and_values = itertools.chain(*[(F.lit(c), F.col(c)) for c in df1.columns])
df2 = df1.withColumn("myMap", F.create_map(*columns_and_values))
```